# How to apply Bootstrap's "text-center" on MD devices and below , and not on larger devices?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, client-side

I have a div that I want to apply Bootstrap's `text-center` class , only on MD devices and below.

Any device above MD , I don't want to apply `text-center` class.

```
<p className='text-capitalize text-center'>
                    Copyright &copy; Tech Store {new Date().getFullYear()} 
                    All Rights Reserved!
</p>
```

Comment: a solution to this would be to use media query and target screens <= 768px

Comment: read the doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-alignment you can add breakpoint as prefixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a bootstrap solution, Use **`text-lg-left`** class by setting 'text-center` as default.

```
  <p className='text-capitalize text-center text-lg-left'>
            Copyright &copy; Tech Store {new Date().getFullYear()} 
             All Rights Reserved!
  </p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98zrva4g/1/)

Comment: You mean `text-lg-left`.

Comment: OK thanks , great it works like a charm `text-center text-lg-left` both

Comment: glad to help :)